# React redux triggering both actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux

I'm having some issues with react redux and async calls.
When I call my api it returns ok and dispatches the correct action and then for some reason that I'm not seeing, some other action is called after that.
The api class is below.

```
class StockApi{
/**
 * function to call the api to search data
 * @param {string} nameofStock stock code to searchs
 * @param {string} startdate start date for search
 * @param {string} enddate end date for search
 */
static getStock(nameofStock,startdate,enddate){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/data/stocksearch?stockName=${nameofStock}&startdate=${startdate}&enddate=${enddate}`)
        .then(response=>{
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(result=>{
            console.log("result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
            //return result;
            resolve(result);

        })
        .catch(error=>{
            console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
            //return {isDataOK:false,ErrorInfo:error,resultData:{}};
            //reject(error.message)
            throw new Error(error.message);
        });
    });

}

}
export default StockApi;
```

The actions defined:

```
import StockApi from '../api/stocksApi';
    import * as types from '../constants/Actiontypes';

    export const requestDataStocks = value => ({
      type: types.REQUEST_STOCKS,
      value
    })
    export const recieveData=result=>({
        type:types.RECIEVE_STOCKS,
        result
    })

    export const recieveDataNOK=error=>({
        type:types.RECIEVE_STOCKS_NOK,
        error

    })

    /**
     * "private" function to process the request information
     * 
     */
    const fetchData=stockData=>dispatch=>{

        dispatch(requestDataStocks(stockData));
        StockApi.getStock(stockData.stockName,stockData.startDate,stockData.endDate)
                .then((result)=>{

                    console.log("item got here: data is ok");
                    dispatch(recieveData(result));

                })
                .catch((err)=>{
                    console.log("got here: data is nok: "+ err);
                    dispatch(recieveDataNOK(err));
                });
    }

    /**
     * checks the state to see if the date exists
     * @param {*} state the state of the app
     * @param {object} stockData information to be searched
     */
    const shouldGetDataStock=(state,stockData)=>{

        if (!state.items){
            console.log("no items");
            return true;
        }
        const datainState=state.items.find(x=>x.searchIndex===stockData.stockName+stockName.startDate+stockName.endDate);

        if (!datainState){
            return true;
        }
        if (datainState.isSearching){
            return false;
        }
        return datainState.didInvalidate;

    }
    /**
     * entry point operation for searching data
     * @param {object} stockData data to be searched
     */
    export const fetchStocksIfNeeded=stockData=>(dispatch, getState)=>{

        if (shouldGetDataStock(getState(),stockData)){
            return dispatch(fetchData(stockData));
        }
    }
```

The reducer:

```
    import {REQUEST_STOCKS,
    RECIEVE_STOCKS,RECIEVE_STOCKS_NOK,
    SET_STOCK_VALUE,
    SET_DATA_START,
    SET_DATA_END
} from '../constants/Actiontypes'

const StockAppReducer= (state = {
    isSearching:false,
    didInvalidate:false,
    stockQuery:'',
    initialDate:'',
    finalDate:'',
    items: []
}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {  
        case REQUEST_STOCKS:
            console.log("reducer REQUEST_STOCKS: "+action.value);
            return {
                ...state,
                isSearching: true,
                didInvalidate: false,
            }
            break;

        case RECIEVE_STOCKS:
            console.log("reducer RECIEVE_STOCKS: "+action.result.stockName);    
            return {
                ...state,
                items: [...state.items, {searchIndex: action.result.stockCode+"-"+action.result.stockQueryStart+"-"+action.result.StockQueryEnd,searchResults:action.result}],
                isSearching:false,
                didInvalidate:false,
                stockQuery:'',
                initialDate:'',
                finalDate:''
            }
            break;
        case RECIEVE_STOCKS_NOK:
            console.log("reducer RECIEVE_STOCKS_NOK: \n error: "+ action.error);
            return{
                ...state,
                isSearching:false,
                didInvalidate:false,
                isSearching:false,
                didInvalidate:false,
                stockQuery:'',
                initialDate:'',
                finalDate:''
            }
            break;


        default:
            return state;

    }

};





export default StockAppReducer;
```

the Actiontypes.js file

```
export const REQUEST_STOCKS='REQUEST_STOCKS';
export const RECIEVE_STOCKS='RECIEVE_STOCKS';
export const RECIEVE_STOCKS_NOK='RECIEVE_STOCKS_NOK';
export const INVALIDATE_STOCK='INVALIDATE_STOCK';
export const SET_DATA_START='DATA_START';
export const SET_DATA_END='DATA_END';
export const SET_STOCK_VALUE='STOCK_SET';
```

So basically `fetchData` is called no problems.
But when the promise resolves from the api, it dispatches the action correctly as I can see it being logged with:

> item got here: data is ok

passes onto the reducer and then I can see that on the reducer (via the console.log) that the `RECIEVE_STOCKS` action is processed and the `RECIEVE_STOCKS_NOK` stating the following:

> error: ReferenceError: StockInformation is not defined

I don't have any stockinformation or whatsoever in my code. I've checked and double checked and no reference to it.

Can anyone please provide some help with this? What might actually be the issue?

Comment: can you share your `Actiontypes` file?

Comment: there you go...forgot about that one